# How to automate Visual Studio Code startup?

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I need to setup my development environment multiple times a day, I want to automate the process to a one-click solution.

The goal is to having a main script which opens up two VS Code instances, one for the frontend, one for the backend project.

The steps should be the following:

```
- open VS Code
- open Backend Project (located at e.g.: C:/myCompany/backend)
- run git pull
- open terminal
- run docker-compose up
- open split terminal
- run npm run start:dev
- open another vscode
- open terminal
- git pull
- open terminal
- run npm run start:dev
```

I am running windows, I can create very basic ps1 files, I know you can use terminal and run 'code' command to start an instance of VS Code. After that I don't find information what to do next.
I know there some kind of scripts you can run in Vs Code too, but I cannot put it all together.

Comment: all git and docker stuff can be done outside VSC, start 2 VSC instances with the correct workspace folder argument, the only thing to do is click a line in the NPM SCRIPTS view

Comment: Thanks, using external terminals could work as last resort, but the *goal* is to have only 2 VS code instances open - terminals inside, and achieve all this with a *single script* or *one mouseclick*.
(We want all the outputs to be in one place.)

Comment: where in my comment so I talk about external terminals? you must have a terminal to call the script that does git and docker and start VSC 2 times, then you have internal terminals in VSC

Comment: you can create an **Auto Hotkey** script

Comment: @rioV8 AutoHotkey would be the way to go if the only approach for the task is simulating clicks and keypresses. That isn't the case here.

Comment: Related: [Start app when opening project in VS Code?](/q/51049955)

Answer (score 1):

There's a certain level of automation that can be achieved with VSCode's tooling itself.

Let's start with the backend part of the project. Inside `C:/myCompany/backend` create a folder `.vscode` and inside of it place two files: `settings.json` and `tasks.json`. They should be as follows:

```json
// C:/myCompany/backend/.vscode/tasks.json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "git pull",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "git pull",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "docker-compose up",
      "command": "docker-compose up",
      "type": "shell",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "dedicated",
        "group": "dev"
      },
      "group": "build",
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "start:dev",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "npm run start:dev",
      "presentation": {
        "panel": "dedicated",
        "group": "dev"
      },
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
// C:/myCompany/backend/.vscode/settings.json
{
  "task.allowAutomaticTasks": "on"
}
```

Similarly, under `C:/myCompany/frontend` create the same `.vscode` folder and the same two files under it; `settings.json` would stay the same, but `tasks.json` would be as follows:

```json
// C:/myCompany/frontend/.vscode/tasks.json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "git pull",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "git pull",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "start:dev",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "npm run start:dev",
      "presentation": {
        "panel": "dedicated",
        "group": "dev"
      },
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To finish things up, the powershell script would be as simple as this:

```
code C:\myCompany\backend
code C:\myCompany\frontend
```

In previous VSCode versions it was necessary to invoke `workbench.action.tasks.manageAutomaticRunning` and then to choose `Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder` once for each folder, but that doesn't seem to be the case any more (the setting in `settings.json` seems to suffice).

For further customisation (e.g. task execution order and dependency), you can look at the documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks. You can also experiment with running `git pull` right from the powershell script instead of the VSCode tasks.